# Jackson XML Mapper set root element with attribute by code

Tags: xml, jackson, serialization

I need to serialize my POJO without `Jackson Xml Annotation`, my custom serializer override serialize method of `StdSerializer class` like this:

```
 @Override
    public void serialize(Caregiver value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeRawValue(value.toString());
    }
```

Then in my POJO class does this:

```
JacksonXmlModule module = new JacksonXmlModule();
        module.addSerializer(Caregiver.class, new CaregiverXml.Serializer());
        return new XmlMapper(module)
                  .writeValueAsString(object);
```

and my output is:

```
<Caregiver>
   <FirstName />
   <LastName />
</Caregiver>
```

but I would like to add and attribute to the root element, which is automatically added by the Object writer I guess, producing this output:

```
<Caregiver num="1">
   <FirstName />
   <LastName />
</Caregiver>
```

Looking on the documentation I found some `ObjectWriter` methods like `withRootName()`, but I am still unable to add the attribute to the root element.